# Is $F = \langle (6,3,0),(-2,-1,5),(0,0,3) \rangle$ where $F = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x = 2y \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

To find this I tried to find out the subspace generated (spanned?) by those 3 given vectors:

$$\langle (6,3,0),(-2,-1,5),(0,0,3) \rangle = (6\alpha_1-2\alpha_1, 3\alpha_2-\alpha_2,5\alpha_3+5\alpha_3) = (4\alpha_1,\alpha_2,10\alpha_3)$$

Putting this in a system and solving it using a matrix I got:

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_1 = x/4 \\
\alpha_2=y\\
\alpha_3=z/10
\end{array}
\right.$$

Because there are no ways this matrix can be impossible (no 0 0 0 rows with possibly non zero right hand values), the subspace is 
$$\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

To know if F is generated by this I have to check if any vector in F can be written as a linear combination of:
$$x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1) \Rightarrow \langle(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$$

Since F is defined as

$$F = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x = 2y \}$$ then
$$(x,y,z)=(2y,y,z)=y(2,1,0)+z(0,0,1) \Rightarrow F = \langle (2,1,0),(0,0,1) \rangle$$

I think that what I need to do here is show that $(2y,y,z)$ can be written as a linear combination of $(x,y,z)$... so I need to use the system I used before and solve for 2y,y and z instead of x,y,z:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
4\alpha_1 = y/2 \\
\alpha_2=y\\
10\alpha_3=z
\end{array}
\right.$$

Putting this on a matrix I get no 0 0 0 rows so x,y and z can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$... my question is, is F generated by these vectors or not? It can be written as a linear combination of them as shown, but the dimension of the subspace generated by the given vectors is 3 while the dimension of F is 2. Can it still be generated if the dimensions are different or is this only an issue if the dimension of the given vectors was 2 and F's was 3? (in other words, if the dimension of the subspace generated by the given vectors was smaller than that of F).

I'm also not entirely sure of how what I did proves that any vector in F can be written as a linear combination of the given vectors... I suppose it's because there are no exceptions to what values x,y and z can take with the given vectors and neither is there for F. Is this correct? If there were "exceptions" in either, could F still be generated by the given vectors?

Comment: When you wrote $(4\alpha_1,\alpha_2,10\alpha_3)$, did you mean $(4\alpha_1,\color{red}2\alpha_2,10\alpha_3)$?

Comment: Near the start what is $(6\alpha_1-2\alpha_1,3\alpha_2-\alpha_2,5\alpha_3+5\alpha_3)$ supposed to be? It certainly is not a linear combination of your three starting vectors. Incidentally, those three vectors do span $F$. $(-2,-1,5)$ is obviously a linear combination of the other two.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner My mistake, let me fix that...

Comment: @almagest It's meant to be a linear combination. How would you write it then?

Comment: What linear combination? Why is the third component $5\alpha_3+5\alpha_3$?

Comment: $a_1(6,3,0)+a_2(-2,-1,5)+a_3(0,0,3)=(6a_1-2a_2,3a_1-a_2,5a_2+3a_3)$

Comment: @almagest I got the values mixed up, fixing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2y,y,z)=\frac{y}{3}(6,3,0)+\frac{z}{3}(0,0,3)\Big)$, so $(6,3,0)$ and $(0,0,3)$ span $F$, and are obviously linearly independent. Also $(-2,-1,5)\in F$. So the subspace generated by the three vectors is $F$.

Comment: Fixed it, yes you are right. I have a question: if the subspaces were different under what conditions could those 2 vectors still generate F?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire If which subspaces were different?

Comment: What I meant was, let's say that the question as whether if F is in the subspace created by those 3 given vectors and not if it's equal. For example, the "condition" in the new subspace is something like x = z/3 instead of x=2y. Does this new subspace generate F?

Comment: So $F$ is something different. Let's call $W$ the subspace generated by the 3 vectors. The question is whether $F\subseteq W$. Yes? So we are only going to have $F\subseteq W$ if (1) $W=F$, or (2) $W=\mathbb{R}^3$, or (3) dim $F$=1 and $F\subset W$.

Comment: I don't understand the last one. Why does dim F have to be equal to 1, and how do you prove $F\subset W$?

Comment: dim $F=2,3$ is covered in the other cases. To prove $F\subseteq W$ you have to show that every vector in $F$ is a linear combination of your 3 starting vectors.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is a two-dimensional subspace ($2$ free variables, closed under addition and scalar multiplication).

But $(6,3,0)$ and $(-2,-1,5)$ are independent vectors in $F$.  The result follows, since $(0,0,3)$ is also in $F$.